# udev rule works only on some machines

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, udev, raspbian

I create a udev rule for Raspbian Stretch:

```
KERNELS=="1-1.5", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SYMLINK+="SH"
```

this will create a symbolic link named "SH" if a tty (USB dongle) is inserted on the USB path "1-1.5". To test it I trigger udevadm or just reboot.

On my desk I have several Raspberry Pi 2 mod. B.
Some of them work as expected, others *don't create the symlink*.

What I did:

- used the same sd-card for all the boards
- used the same USB dongle for all the boards
- (of course) put the USB dongle in the same port for all boards

Then, I tried to look for any differences.
USB path is the same:

```
$ udevadm info --name /dev/ttyUSB0
P: /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0
N: ttyUSB0
...
```

this output is the same for both working and not working boards.
RPi revision is the same:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
...
processor   : 3
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 38.40
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

Hardware    : BCM2835
Revision    : a01041
Serial      : 00000000cb33e91e
```

How should I investigate further to understand why the same rule doesn't work on similar machines?

Comment: What is the output of dmesg when performing the action?

Comment: Check the output from `udevadm monitor` or run `udevd` in `--debug` mode for the duration of the test.

Comment: @RamanSailopal I see nothing new in dmesg in both cases

Comment: @FerencWágner in the meanwhile I have the opportunity to replicate this issue, your hint helped me to fix another problem. Cool!